# live-server HTTPS redirection

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost, middleware, npm-live-server

Is there any way to upgrade insecure requests on a local development server?

Using [live-server](https://github.com/tapio/live-server):

```
live-server --https="C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\live-server-https" --port=443 --host=livereload
```

Tried using a middleware, then noticed that since the server isn't listening on port 80 no requests get through to the middleware.

Comment: Busted! You did not [read the docs](https://github.com/tapio/live-server#https) :)

Comment: Not busted, read more carefully. I can do HTTPS, but I can't do **HTTP-to-HTTPS redirection.** A `GET` request to `http://localhost/index.html` would fail instead of get redirected to `https://localhost/index.html`